# Show ToolBar over TabBar

Tags: iphone

In my app I would like to replace the TabBar with a ToolBar under certain conditions, similar to what happens in the Photos App when a user places it in selections mode (A toolbar with share copy, etc, buttons appear over the tab bar). How can I achieve this please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be achieved by creating a new toolbar, assigning it an appropriate frame and adding it to self.tabBarController.view

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming your root view controller is a UITabBarController.  Sometimes using the canned "Root" UIViewControllers is more of a hindrance than a help, especially if you want a highly custom look that does not fit into the paradigm of what the canned controllers offer.   There's no reason you *have* to use them -- you could write your own, and do your own transition between your sub-UIViewController views onto the screen.   You can use the UITabBar without the UITabBarController in your own custom UIViewController subclass, then you don't end up fighting the behavior of UITabBarController.    Writing your own root ViewController can be very instructive as well -- you learn about all the things a root ViewController must do to manage the sub-ViewControllers.